# Why do I always get empty value

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I'm trying to make a module to **webscrape** data for this site to excel but I keep geting empty value can anyone help me

so here's my module

```
Sub StockRetrieve()

    Dim bot As New WebDriver
    
    bot.Get "https://stockbit.com/#/symbol/NELY/financials"
    
    bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='content-box']/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/select").Click
    bot.FindElementByXPath("//option[@value='bs']").Click
    asset2020 = bot.FindElementByXPath("//table[contains(@class,'fin-table')]/tbody/tr[23]/td[2]").TextAsNumber
    Sheets(1).Range("B2").Value = asset2020

    Stop
End Sub
```

Comment: Which value do you want to get? What are the steps?

Comment: Add html code to your question, the site requires login

Comment: The website is kind of slow ~1s (just for the login page), you might have to wait for the elements to load first.

Comment: the value in FindElementByXPath("//table[contains(@class,'fin-table')]/tbody/tr[23]/td[2]") it always reads empty

Comment: Have you tried verifying your locators on the page using the dev console? In Chrome, open the dev console and you can use `$$()` for CSS selectors and `$x()` for XPaths. In your third case, you can use `$x("//table[contains(@class,'fin-table')]/tbody/tr[23]/td[2]")` to see if you are getting the expected element. You can also use `$x("//table[contains(@class,'fin-table')]/tbody/tr[23]/td[2]").text` to see what text is in that element.

Comment: Also, I don't do VBA... is there a property you can use other than `.TextAsNumber`? Maybe just `.Text` or the equivalent? Maybe try that. The text returned may not qualify as a number because it has extra spaces or currency symbols, etc. and empty string is VBA's way of not throwing an exception in that case.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that one or more of the paths is wrong. Step through the code and verify the value of *elem* at every step. If everything looks good, then are you sure that the value you're trying to read is not empty?

```
Sub StockRetrieve()

    Dim bot As New WebDriver
    Dim elem as Variant

    bot.Get "https://stockbit.com/#/symbol/NELY/financials"

    elem = bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='content-box']/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/select")
    elem.Click 

    elem = bot.FindElementByXPath("//option[@value='bs']")
    elem.Click 

    elem = bot.FindElementByXPath("//table[contains(@class,'fin-table')]/tbody/tr[23]/td[2]")

    asset2020 = elem.TextAsNumber 
    Sheets(1).Range("B2").Value = asset2020

End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't create a variable `elem` and then keep reusing it to store every element in the method. It makes it really hard to read and difficult to debug. If you aren't going to reuse the element, there's really no need to store it in a variable at all. OP's code is a better practice there. For the first two lines, the elements are being clicked. If the click succeeds, there's no need to check the value of `elem` on those steps. For the last one, the value is literally stored in `asset2020` so OP can already check that using his code.

Comment: The purpose of the variable elem is to allow the user to check the returned value easily while stepping through the code. This is not necessarily the approach I would take if I had access to the WebDriver library and the website itself, but it gives OP a starting point to identify which statement is in error.

Comment: I read your answer and understood that but I made the point in my comment that that approach was not necessary here for the reasons I provided. Also future readers may mistakenly take that as a OK/good practice for coding.